# MongooseJS Update API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a 404 issue with my NodeJS API. I don't know if I am quite doing it right, I tried referring to documentation, and I feel like it's close.

**MongoDB Schema**

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({

local: {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    handle: String,
    pic: {data: Buffer, contentType: String}
}
```

});

**NodeJS UPDATE API**

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res, user) {
        User.update({email : user.email, 
                     password : user.password, 
                     handle : user.handle, 
                     pic : user.pic},
                    {$set: {
                        email : req.body.email,
                        password : req.body.email,
                        handle : req.body.handle,
                        pic : req.body.pic,
                        done : false
                    }

        }, function(err, users) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });
    });
```

**Controller POST API call**

```
$scope.editProfile = function() {
    $http.post('/api/users', $scope.editFormData)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
    })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing a post call correct. You can't pass your post object in the URL. Your node post should look like this.

```
app.post('/api', upload.array(), function(req, res) {
    var body = req.body; //body will be your post object
});
```

For a post to work you need to make sure you have the proper things added to your Node Project. The above example is using ExpressJS with `require('body-parser')` and `require('multer')`. The example you are showing will never show as a true path. For reference here is how you would do a get in node.

```
app.get('/getcall/*', function(){
 // the * denotes any singleton parameter you wanted to pass in.
})
```

Here are the references I use in all my node projects. These are the basics.

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    upload = multer(),
    path = require('path'),
    request = require('request'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http');
```

Also as for your angular call an $http.post looks like this and you should be using `.then` instead of `.success`.

```
$http.post('/api', $scope.editFormData)
        .then(function successCallback(resp) {
            console.log(resp.data)
        }, function errorCallback(resp) {
            console.log(resp)
        });
```